# Does Bootstrap cdn links for css and javascript work in CRM?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, bootstrap-modal

I have included the Bootstrap cdn links for using in  HTML web-Resource code for CRM development. I have designed a HTML page using those Bootstrap functionalities. As a html page outside CRM it was working fine but when I added it to CRM Page as HTML web resource what it was displaying is a basic html page without css and javascript features.

How can I solve this?

Comment: We have a PCs component in one of our instance which uses bootstrap and using bootstrap css kind of messed with dynamics css. Especially with regards to global search and views. I would try to avoid bootstrap as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I never used CDN source in my CRM web resource developments. Always have a local copy uploaded in CRM as web resource to refer in HTML pages and checked into Azure DevOps as well. I never faced any issues in this approach. I remember CDN url broke like you said when I tried last time.

Just sharing the url paths from `<head>` section that I'm using in one of my HTML web resource.

```
<script src="mts_jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="mts_typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<script src="mts_bootstrap/3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="mts_bootstrap/3.3.5/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="mts_bootstrap/3.3.5/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="mts_bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<link href="mts_bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

> [image]