# Microsoft Model driven application css support

Tags: css, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I made a Microsoft Model driven application I need to integrate third party libraries like Bootstrap etc. Is there any way to customize css or support for the third party libraries for the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the custom css file as Dynamics CRM (aka Model driven PowerApps) web resources and use them as needed further.

Same way, third party libraries like Bootstrap JS, css files also can be uploaded as CRM web resource files, some people prefer the cdn files as well.

[Read my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60569855)